# Running levenshtein is taking more time in R

Tags: r

I want to apply levenshtein on 2 columns - s1$Response and s2$Response, later I need to filter them by <0.4 and bind them as Var1 and Var2.
Following code, when I run, its taking too much time as there are lot of records (its taking hours) to execute. Please help me in making it faster by giving any alternative.

```
 kk=cross2(.x = s2$Response, .y = s1$Response, .filter = ~levenshteinSim(.x, .y) < 0.4) %>% map(set_names, c("var1", "var2")) %>% bind_rows()
```

Comment: If this is running `levenshteinSim` every time for every combination of `s1` and `s2` it will be painfully slow. Maybe make a list of all the combinations of `s1`/`s2` first and then run `levenshteinSim` once?

Comment: Any other alternative way of writing the above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Original answer assumed both string vectors were same length when creating tibble.

Here's an approach that compares two vectors of 1000 strings (1M combinations). How long are the columns you are working with? If much longer, and assuming you need to compare every element of each to every element in the other, it require a different approach.

```
library(tidyverse); library(stringdist)
set.seed(42)
Response1 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000, 6)
Response2 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000, 6)

# EDIT, should work for different length vectors
combos <- expand.grid(Response1, Response2, stringsAsFactors = F) %>%
    as_tibble() %>%

  # Here, levenshtein distance based on the average length of the two strings
  mutate(distance = stringdist(Var1, Var2, method = "lv") / 
           (nchar(Var1) + nchar(Var2) / 2)) %>%
  filter(distance < 0.4)
```

Comment: s1$Response has 2193 rows, s2$Response has 45

Comment: Ok, then I would expect this to work very fast, since that's under 100k comparisons.

Comment: After reading s1 and s2 csv files, how do I pass the respective column  in below one: Response1 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000, 6)
Response2 = stringi::stri_rand_strings(1000, 6)

Comment: Those were to generate fake data. Replace `Response1` with `s1$Response` and `Response2` with `s2$Response` in the `combos <- ...` line.

Comment: s1$Response = stringi::stri_rand_strings
s2$Response = stringi::stri_rand_strings

combos <- tibble(Var1 = s2$Response, Var2 = s1$Response) %>%
  expand(Var1, Var2) %>%
  # Here, levenshtein distance based on the average length of the two strings
  mutate(distance = stringdist(Var1, Var2, method = "lv") / 
           (nchar(Var1) + nchar(Var2) / 2)) %>%
  filter(distance < 0.4)]
Error: Column `Var1` must be length 1 or 2193, not 45 ; when I tried giving var1 as s1$Response as its 2193 length, but it gives error again

Comment: Edited to accommodate vectors of unequal length.

Comment: In another case I have s1=241339 rows and s2=340, its been running from one hour now, what needs to be done to fasten it.

Comment: That's 82 million comparisons, which will be slow. Perhaps try it in batches, with the first 120k of s1 first, then then 2nd half?

Comment: how to include parallelization / thread in the above code so that it executes fast, as its taking very long time.

Answer (score 2):

If your code is running `levenshteinSim` as a function call every time for every combination of `s1` and `s2` it will be painfully slow. Maybe make a list of all the combinations of `s1`/`s2` first and then run `levenshteinSim` once in a vectorised fashion? This should be orders of magnitude faster:

```
library(dplyr); library(purrr); library(RecordLinkage)

s1 <- rep(c("paul","patty","harris"), 80)
s2 <- rep(c("darren", "natty", "haris", "paulie"), 80)

system.time({
  egs <- expand.grid(s1, s2, stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
  lv  <- do.call(levenshteinSim, unname(egs))
  egs <- egs[!(lv > 0.6),]
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   0.11    0.00    0.1

system.time({
  cross2(.x = s1, .y = s2, .filter = ~levenshteinSim(.x, .y) > 0.6)
})
#   user  system elapsed 
#   2.98    0.00    2.97
```

Comment: I tried above code, but its giving 57600 rows which is not expected

Comment: @alice - and? This is data I've made up, so I'm not sure what you're expecting.